# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type. Return structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, parameter-passing

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I want to pass a struct pointer from inside a function to use it outside (I know I could pass the whole struct but I want to learn to user pointers properly).

This is the function:

```
struct tm* GetActualTime()
{
//VAR DECLARE
time_t rawtime;
struct tm *timeinfo=malloc(sizeof(struct tm));

time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
return timeinfo;
}
```

And this is how I call it in main:

```
int main(void){
struct tm *real_time;

real_time=GetActualTime();
printf("%d:%d%d",real_time->tm_hour,real_time->tm_min,real_time->tm_sec);
}
```

I get the error:

```
dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

I already looked for this error and I know that there are more threads but it only refers to problems such as: bad struct declaration (witch I think it's not a problem since it's a struct from the time.h lib) or bad call (instead of rea)

Comment: you have to include `time.h` or you won't get access to data members.

Comment: I already have that in another file, I have not shown my prototypes.h (where I have my function prototypes) and myf.h where I call all the libs. I don't have problems with libs because I can print the time inside the function

Comment: the posted code is missing these statements: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>`   EVERY file that uses some item from a header file must have the `#include` statement for that header file,

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `stdlib.h` and `time.h` file,`stdlib.h` for malloc and time.h for time related functions. With this inclusion program run successfully.. I had checked and it give proper output.

Comment: There are other problems with the code too.  For example, it leaks memory, and returns a pointer to memory provided by the time functions in the standard library that will be reused (change) when the library functions are called again.

Comment: Please notice that if I call that printf inside my function with the var timeinfo->tmr_hour, etc I have the desired output. What I'm not managing to do is to return the pointer and use it outside my function

Comment: and how do I solve that problem?
I know I have to free(real_time) but how can I stop leaking the memory by calling the function again?

Answer (score 0):

You are all right, I am calling the lib in another .c file but I use it in the main, but since I was not getting an lib error I always assumed that my code was wrong and that I was missing something regarding pointers.

I'm sorry to waste your time and thank you for helping solving the problem.
Best regards to everyone.

Comment: this answer is not quite correct, suggest removing it

Answer (score 0):

The following code outputs the correct time.

Notice the modification to the format string in the call to `printf()`

Notice the data from `localtime()` is copied into the allocated memory

Notice the usage of the function: `memcpy()` rather than `strncpy()` because some bytes in the `struct tm` will be 0x00, which would stop the `strncopy()` function from copying all the data.

Notice the allocated memory is passed to `free()` when done with it.

Notice the `#include` statements

Notice the consistent indenting of the code:  I.E. indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'.  I used 4 spaces for every indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.  Never use tabs for indenting as each wordprocessor, editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.

Note: if the function: `struct tm* GetActualTime()` is in a separate file from the file containing the `main()` function, then there should be a 'home grown' header file (one you wrote) that contains the prototype for the function.  That header file should be `#include`d in the file that contains the `main()` function.

Such a header file would look something like this:

```
#ifndef GETACTUALTIME_H
#define GETACTUALTIME_H
#include <time.h>  // struct tm
struct tm *GetActualTime( void );
#endif // GETACTUALTIME_H
```

and now, the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf()
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc(), free()
#include <time.h>   // time(), localtime(), time_t, struct tm
#include <string.h> // memcpy()

struct tm* GetActualTime()
{
    //VAR DECLARE
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm *timeinfo=malloc(sizeof(struct tm));

    time ( &rawtime );
    memcpy(timeinfo, localtime(&rawtime), sizeof(struct tm) );
    return timeinfo;
} // end function: GetActualTime


int main(void)
{
    struct tm *real_time;

    real_time=GetActualTime();
    printf("%d:%d:%d",real_time->tm_hour, real_time->tm_min, real_time->tm_sec);
    free( real_time );
} // end function: main
```

Comment: it should be noted:  when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  I did not do that check in the answer I supplied